# Cross-context transaction where one context belongs to the UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

My application is a Web API which uses .NET 6, Identity, Entity Framework Core and SQL Server.

It has 2 db contexts, one for general use by the application and one for use by Identity. The Application db context includes most of the database tables, while the Identity db context only includes those tables required for identity management. They both connect to the same database.

I have a use case where I'd like to create a user via the Identity UserManager, then create some application records, and save the whole lot in a single transaction.

According to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#share-connection-and-transaction), it should be possible to create a transaction across 2 db contexts. I've tried to replicate the sample code from the docs but I can't figure out how to access the db context for the UserManager. I'm using dependency injection to create my db contexts and UserManager.

```
app.MapPost("/MyExampleEndpoint",
async (
       [FromServices] UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
       [FromServices] ApplicationDbContext applicationContext,
       HttpResponse response) =>
{

    //create transaction for Application context
    using var transaction = applicationContext.Database.BeginTransaction(); 

    var userManagerContext = ????;          // How do I get the Identity context for the UserManager?
    
    //add Identity context to the transaction
    userManagerContext.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());

    try
    {
        //create records using Identity context
        await userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser { UserName = "username" });

        //create records using Application context
        applicationContext.MyRecords.Add(new MyRecord { Id = Guid.NewGuid() /* other fields etc */});
        applicationContext.SaveChanges();

        //commit both in a single transaction
        transaction.Commit();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

});
```

Furthermore, the sample code in the docs uses 2 contexts of the same type (both are BloggingContext). My contexts are of different types (ApplicationContext and IdentityContext), and I'm wondering if this will be a problem.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Am I taking the right approach?
2. If so, how can I access the UserManager's db context?
3. Will it work if my db contexts are of different types, albeit using the same connection to the same database?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get another dbcontext with the same way you get theApplicationDbContext,and I tested with the codes：

```
app.MapPost("/MyExampleEndpoint",
async (
       [FromServices] IdentityDBContext identityContext1,
       [FromServices] ApplicationDbContext applicationContext2,
       HttpResponse response) =>
{
    using (var transaction = identityContext1.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = "name1"
        };
        identityContext1.IdentityUser.Add(user);
        identityContext1.SaveChanges();
        applicationContext2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
        applicationContext2.ApplicationUser.Add(new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "name1"
        });
        applicationContext2.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
       
    }
});
```

and the error occurs:
[image: error]

So I don't think you will approach the result you excepted  with contexts which are of different types, even if in the same database.

[image: DB]

and if the two dbcontext  instance are the instance of same Dbcontext,it will work well
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your code and it actually works for me. To avoid the error, you need to make sure both contexts are using the same SqlConnection, like this:

`var mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(mySqlConnection));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(mySqlConnection));`

So this answers my 3rd question: It will work if the contexts are of different types, if they use the same connection.

Comment: Since the Identity and Application tables are all in the same database, your application context could inherit from IdentityDBContext and the same context can be used for both purposes.